# How to create a Scroll in GridView using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

How do I create a scroll in GridView using ASP.NET without using fixed sized div's around it like shown here http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/gridviewscroll-aspnet2-csharp.aspx .

Answer (score 4):

You can set the div's width or height to a percentage as well, and with `overflow:auto`, the div contents will scroll if the browser is sized to less than the content.

Without any size settings, your div will simply expand to hold all content, so a percentage, fixed, or inherited size in at least one dimension is required for scrolling to ever occur.

Comment: Should something like this work: `<div style="overflow:auto;width=50%">` ? Because I have tried it with no success.

Comment: @Coral, that should work in some situations. Without seeing the context of your gridview, it's hard to say. Your best bet is to come up with a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your problem and post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a scroll bar, you need a fixed height container with overflow set to scroll.

Whether you do it with the grid's properties, like in the example you linked, or by just wrapping it in a Panel with a height and overflow set on it, it doesn't matter much.  The key thing is just to get it inside a fixed height container.   How you want the UI to look (where the scrollbar is, etc.) will dictate where you create the div.